# Android widget avoid updating

Tags: android, widget, updates

I am building a static android widget, which means the widget doesn't need to be updated at all. The only thing that widget need to handle is open link from browser when it is triggered.

In the AppWidgetProviderInfo Metadata xml file, there is one attribute called "updatePeriodMillis", and should I set any value there? or just don't add this attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just override onUpdate() in your AppWidgetProvider class and have it do nothing.

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, Geore, just one question, where should I put my button onclick listener in if do nothing in OnUpdate?

Comment: @David_Wang take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326508/is-there-any-oncreate-method-for-android-widgets) question

Comment: Geore Shg, Thanks for the tips. I have tried to not set any value for the "updatePeriodMillis", and I still put all my button onclick listener within the onUpdate(). I didn't check so much how often will the widget keep updating, but so far it is all right now:)

Answer (score 0):

in your widgetprovider file write this method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
    int idd[];
    idd = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
    // call updateAppWidget for each widget
    for (int appWidgetID : ids) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetID);
    }
super.onReceive(context, intent);
}


public void updateAppWidget(Context context,AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId){
    RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout1_1);
    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_days, "" + tmp_diffrentDays);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
}
```

try above code it will work for me

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, but Currently I just don't set the updatePeriodMillis in xml.

Comment: for updating wideget periodically you have to put alaram manager i thingk there is some issue in updatePeridMillis. when i had mad widget i cannot update using updatePerodMillis so i had use Alaram Manager.

Comment: ok then in your update widger file if you cnanot change value then it will not update